# Regex to find time durations

Tags: java, regex

I have read many of the regex questions on stackoverflow, but they didn't help me to develop my own code.

What I need is like the following. I am parsing texts which have already been parsed using [Stanford Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/). Now, I am trying to remove the time durations in some parts of the texts: 1) The phrase starts with the date (e.g. `1999_CARD Tom_NN was_VP`) 2) when the time duration follows this format: `2/1999_CARD -_- 01/01/2000_CARD` (or similar ones).

I have developed a code. But it's wrongly removing some other parts. I don't know why. My regex is like the following

```
    String regex = "(\\s|\\b.*?_(CARD|CD)\\s([^A-Za-z0-9])+_([^A-Za-z0-9])+(.*?)+_(CARD|CD))|(\\b.*?_(CARD|CD))";
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m2 = pattern2.matcher(chunkPhrase);
        if (m2.find()) {

            chunkPhrase = chunkPhrase.replace(m2.group(0), "");
        }
```

For example, in the following phrase, it finds something (but it shouldn't)

```
Â·_NNP Research_NNP of_IN Symbian_NNP OS_NNP 7.0_CD s_NNS
```

After removing the time duration in the above phrase, I'm left with `Â· s_NNS` which is not what I want.

To make it more clear what I expect the code, here are some examples:

```
1/1/2002_CD -_- 1/2/2003_CD Test_NN Company_NN
```

after applying the code, I expect:

```
Test_NN Company_NN
```

For this one:

```
1/1/2002_CARD -_- 1/2/2003_CARD Test_NN Company_NN
```

after applying the code, I expect:

```
Test_NN Company_NN
```

For this one:

```
2000_CARD I_NN was_VP working_NP here_ADV
```

after applying the code, I expect:

```
I_NN was_VP working_NP here_ADV
```

For this one:

```
I_NN have_VP worked_VP in_PP 3_CARD companies_NP
```

after applying the code, I expect:

```
I_NN have_VP worked_VP in_PP 3_CARD companies_NP
```

Meanwhile, I use `java`.

Update: To clarify better: If a number occurs AT THE BEGINNING, it must be removed. Otherwise, it must be remained. If it follows the second format (e.g. `1999_CD -_- 2000_CARD`), it must be removed, indifferent if it occurs at the beginning or middle or end of the phrase.

Can anyone help what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `\b.*?_(CARD|CD)` is the culprit.

Comment: @anubhava could you please explain more? In any case, it must be followed by a non-alphanumeric word to be captured. But it's not.

Comment: I don't have clarity on what you are trying to match and what you are not. May be rather than code you should show few samples of valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: @anubhava I updated the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
final String regex = "\\b(?:\\d{1,2}/*\\d{1,2}/)?\\d{4}_(?:CARD|CD)(?:\\h*[-_]+)?\\h*";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll("");

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FusS4P/3)

---

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b` - Word boundary
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

  - `\d{1,2}/*\d{1,2}/` - Match mm/dd part of a date
- `)?` - End non-capturing group (**optional**)
- `\d{4}` - Match 4 digits of year
- `_` - Match a literal `_`
- `(?:CARD|CD)` - Match `CARD` or `CD`
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

  - `\h*[-_]+` - Match horizontal whitespace followed by 1 or more `-` or `_`
- `)?` - End non-capturing group (**optional**)
- `\h*` - Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces

Comment: :) not really... `\h` works in Java (starting from Java 8) [Check official Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: I see. But since it is not supported in older versions, and it is a good idea to keep to the proven `\s`.

Comment: Sure `\s` can be used for older Java versions but Java 8 is fairly old and Java 9 is also releasing next month.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot. But could you please explain your code in details? For simplification reasons, I didn't include everything in my question and now I have problems in applying changes. If you would like to know the changes I would like to make, I want to let let "any non-alphanumeric character" occur instead of "-" and any tag for this non-alphanumeric character after the "" sign? That is, 2002_CARD ,, 2002_CD and 1/2000_CD !_XY 2004_CARD must also be accepted. Also 2/2004 is also accepted (I mean just month and year).

Comment: I have added detailed regex breakup in answer. Answer can only solve the problem described in question.

Comment: @anubhava sorry, I checked it again and it doesn't solve the problem. If you change "I_NN have_VP worked_VP in_PP 3_CARD companies_NP" to "I_NN have_VP worked_VP in_PP 3333_CARD companies_NP", it doesn't work anymore. In other words, the current regex remove any number with 4 digits.

Comment: You have an example string: `2000_CARD I_NN was_VP working_NP here_ADV` that want you to become `I_NN was_VP working_NP here_ADV` which is basically removing `<4 digits>_CARD` pattern. Now you are complaining that `3333_CARD` is being removed. Think about these 2 cases and come up with clear set of requirements by updating your question.

Comment: @anubhava That is what exactly I have mentioned in the question. If the number comes AT THE BEGINNING, it must be removed. Otherwise, it must be remained. If it follows the second format (e.g. 1999-2000 ), it must be removed, indifferent where it occurs.

Comment: ok then you can use this regex [`(?:^\d{4}|\b\d{1,2}/*\d{1,2}/\d{4}|\b\d{4}-\d{4})_(?:CARD|CD)(?:\h*[-_]+)?\h*`](https://regex101.com/r/FusS4P/4) Let me know if this works out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples you have provided, the following regex will capture the required time durations

```
((?:\d{2,}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})_(?:CARD|CD) (?:-_- )?)
```

**Details**

```
(?:\d{2,}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})  // match minimum of 2 digits or a date in xx/xx/xx[xx] format

_(?:CARD|CD)  // match _CARD or _CD

(?:-_- )?  // match -_- , if it exists
```

The `?:` at the beginning mean these are non-capturing groups. The parentheses around the whole thing is the capturing group

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rxIPp9/2)